# Help identifying flash memory chip

Tags: identification, flash, flash-memories

I'm trying to find the datasheet and/or documentation of the flash memory chips on this SSD drive board. The chip is marked `29F32B2ALCMG2`, and though my web searches did not come up with any sources, I did find many Chinese forums discussing the chip.

I have some hints the chip might have been made by Intel, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions?

[image: Layout of the board]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Intel NAND flash chip. You can find it under the article number "PF29F32B2ALCMG2S LMBA" on Mouser (there is no stock though). Finding a data sheet for this particular chip is difficult, because Intel doesn't seem to make them available to the public. I could find a datasheet for a similar chip that may give some hints about this one:

[image: Intel NAND info]

With this information PF29F32B2ALCMG2S seems to mean:

```
PF -> BGA package
29F -> NAND Flash memory
32B -> 256 Gbits
2A -> Probably device bus identifier
L -> 1 Die, 1 CE, 1 R/B
C -> 3.3V
M -> MLC NAND Flash Memory
G2 -> Probably litography code
S -> Client SKU
```

Maybe someone else will find the exact datasheet.